# Дополнительные ряды в InlineKeyboardButton в Telegram Bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Есть код который создает разметку клавиатуры в два ряда. Что-то такое:

```
var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
           new InlineKeyboardButton[][]{
                           new [] {
                             new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Вверх","North"),
                             new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Вниз","South")},
                           new [] {
                             new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Влево","West"),
                             new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Вправо","East")},     


                                  });
```

Выдает такую разметку:

[image: Результат]

Нужно добавить еще один ряд с кнопками чтобы получилось вот так (пример)[image: Вот так надо]

В [библиотеке](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot) реализован интерфейс IReplyMarkup в котором ничего нет. Вопрос в том как добавить больше рядов кнопок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается [][] это массив массивов, а не два массива. Так что надо было просто добавить еще массив.

```
    var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
       new InlineKeyboardButton[][]{
                       new [] {
                         new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Вверх","North"),
                         new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Вниз","South")},
                       new [] {
                         new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Влево","West"),
                         new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Вправо","East")},
                       new [] {
                         new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Влево","West"),
                         new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Вправо","East")},
                              });
```

Вот так работает